# What's the correct way of calculate the entropy of a variable?

Tags: matlab, entropy, information-extraction

Example:

If a have a variable **X=[1 2 2 0]**, what's the correct way of calculating the entropy?

My attempt (using MATLAB):

> p(1) = 1/4; % probably of occur 1
>
> p(2) = 2/4; % probably of occur 2
>
> p(0) = 1/4; % probably of occur 0

```
H = -(1/4*log2(1/4)+2/4*log2(2/4)+1/4*log2(1/4))
  = 1.5
```

The problem and my confusion is, should I consider the zero values of *X*?
Using the `entropy` function of MATLAB I get the same value.

Thank you.

Comment: The [documentation  for `entropy`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) tells you exactly how it's calculated. If you are getting the same value as a MATLAB in-built (which you consider to be correct?), then what are you asking?

Comment: Probably you missed it, but I ask again, should I consider the zero values of X?

Comment: Probably you missed it, but I ask again, what are you asking? You have a method, it returns some value. Is this value correct? Do you not know whether this value is correct? Are you asking whether the Matlab function `entropy` gives the correct value (since it's the same as your value)? What is the mathematical equation which you are trying to convert to a function? What are `X` or `p` doing in your example, as they are not used? **You need to describe a specific problem, with your expected and current results to demonstrate what the issue is**

Comment: I thought using the tags (such as entropy), I was filtering...Apparently not.

Comment: There are only 25 followers of the `entropy` tag and 93 for `information-extraction` (compared to, say, the 40k for `matlab`) meaning you are unlikely to find a specialist! You need to describe what you're trying to achieve or we can't help you, simple as that.

Comment: Don’t use the way I put my question and the number of followers to justify your lack of knowledge on the main topic (entropy).

Comment: @Dirac I think you'll find [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) has the expertise you're looking for if you're not happy here.

Comment: Tell me about it! ;) @SecretAgentMan thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you are attempting to do.

If `X` represents the data associated to a greyscale image, then the [entropy function](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) is what you are looking for:

```
X = [1 2 2 0];
H = entropy(X); % 0.811278124459133
```

But neither your `X` variable, nor your expected result (`1.5`) point to that solution. To me, it seems like you are just attempting to calculate the Shannon's entropy on a vector of random values. Hence, you must use a different approach:

```
X = [1 2 2 0];

% Build the probabilities vector according to X...

X_uni = unique(X);
X_uni_size = numel(X_uni);

P = zeros(X_uni_size,1);

for i = 1:X_uni_size
    P(i) = sum(X == X_uni(i));
end

P = P ./ numel(X);

% Compute the Shannon's Entropy

H = -sum(P .* log2(P)); % 1.5
```

`P` must sum to `1` and probabilities (not values) equal to zero must be excluded to the computation (using the code above , it's not possible to produce such probabilities so it's not necessary to handle them).

Why are the results different? That's very simple to explain. In the first example (the one that uses the [entropy function](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html)), Matlab is forced to treat `X` as a grayscale image (a matrix whose values are either between `0` and `1` or ranging from `0` to `255`). Since the underlying type of `X` is `double`, the variable is internally transformed by the function `im2uint8` so that all his values fall within the correct range of a greyscale image... thus obtaining:

```
X = [255 255 255 0];
```

This produces a different vector of probabilities, equal to:

```
P = [0.25 0.75];
```

that produces a Shannon's entropy index equal to `0.811278124459133`.